# Symlink vue to vuejs

Tags: discussion, status-completed, synonym-request

[vue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vue) Questions: 4, 100% also tagged with vuejs

> Vue (pronounced /vjuː/, like view) is a progressive framework for building user interfaces. Unlike other monolithic frameworks, Vue is designed from the ground up to be incrementally adoptable.

Contains no tag wiki

[vuejs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vuejs) Questions: 10375

> Vue.js is an open-source, progressive Javascript framework for building user interfaces that aims to be incrementally adoptable. The core library is focused on a reactive view.

Contains a large tag wiki

---

I'm asking [vue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vue) to be symlinked to [vuejs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vuejs) because these tags basicly point to the same thing. Even though these tags are the same, manually retagging is ineffective because questions are created faster than 1 question a day, keeping the [vue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vue) tag safe from the tag goomba.

Comment: Looks like a syn was proposed yesterday for vue->vue.js so I've approved that now.